# JMeter -> HTTPSampler error java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET on PUT request

Tags: http, jmeter, put

I've got a really perplexing problem in JMeter. I'm building a REST webservice regression test plan, and the GETs POSTs and DELETEs are working well. Unfortunately, whenever I attempt a PUT, I'm getting the error

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET
```

Stack trace:

```
2013/01/04 13:18:18 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sendEntityData(HTTPHC4Impl.java:1023)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:281)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1075)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1064)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:426)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:255)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I've tried a number of things: I added a content type to the Content encoding field, tried commenting out this line in the test plan:

```
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
```

But none of it is working. This is the request I'm making (sanitised):

```
URL: ${PATH_TO_SERVICE}/${ID}/category/${CAT_ID}

BODY:
{
    "id":"xxxxxxx",
    "name":"AUTOREGRESSION",
    "icon":"HOME",
    "Key" :"99949"
}

HEADERS: 
Content-Type : application/json
Accept : application/json
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks.

Comment: I should also mention that I've looked through the JMeter docs and I can't find any mention of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using a standard JMeter 2.8 or did you change some jars ?

This error is mentionned here:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPASYNC-21

Can you open a bug in JMeter bugzilla with a simple Test Plan showing issue ? 
You can also try JMeter nightly build which contains more recent versions of HttpComponents:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html (read carefully Building JMeter )

Comment: I'm using jmeter-plugins. I'll try a vanilla install and get back.

Comment: This is so strange. I removed the jmeter-plugins-dependent stuff and ran it and it worked. So I thought "Right, I need to reproduce this" (I am primarily a tester after all). Then I replaced the plugins and it still worked. I'm baffled, but I think we can consider this closed unless I can reproduce it again.

Comment: I'm feeling better with it. At the moment, I'm using a mixture of JMeter and Ruby/JRuby for functional testing. Switching to a groovy or Scala solution would help with integration. The only realy problem I have with JMeter is that the interface is clunky and I've occasionally lost work because of careless slips.

Comment: If you have some ideas regarding possible enhancements then why not submitting a BugZilla. Same for what you find clunky in GUI, send a mail to user list or to me, I would be interested

Comment: Thanks - should I send to the User or Dev list?

Comment: As you like, there are more people on user list.